# Discord.py - How do you edit an image sent to a channel (not an embed)

Tags: discord.py

Does anyone know how to update the image in a post using message.edit, without it being in an embed? I have seen midjourney are able to do it but I cannot work it out.

I have been converting images to BytesIO objects and then posted them as discord files. In the documentation you cannot edit the file parameter however.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The `message.edit` function does allow you to edit attachments by providing the new list of attachments:

```py
file = discord.File("./path_to_your_file.png", filename="your_file.png")
await message.edit(attachments=[file])
```

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.Message.edit

Comment: Great! is it possible to do this using a URL provided by an image hosting website?

Comment: @Questionner If you just post a link to an image on discord, it will be automatically displayed (Most of the time anyways). Then you can just edit the link inside the message content. A lot easier than having to deal with the files :)